# Text processing to create a list of unique ID's

Tags: awk, sed

I Have a file with ID’s and Names applicable to them as below:

```
1234|abc|cde|fgh
5678|ijk|abc|lmn
9101|cde|fgh|klm
1213|klm|abc|cde
```

I need a file with only **unique Names** as a list.

Output File:

```
abc|sysdate
cde|sysdate
fgh|sysdate
ijk|sysdate
lmn|sysdate
klm|sysdate
```

Where sysdate is the current timestamp of processing.

Requesting you to help on this. Also requesting for a explanation for the code suggested.

Comment: the downvotes you see is probably due to not including what you have tried yourself to solve this issue, which is required on stackoverflow.. `awk` is a good choice for this problem, visit https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for learning resources and other helpful links

Comment: I am completely new to awk... and hence seeking help... so that i can learn with realtime solutions.I have tried `awk -F\| '{ for(i=2; i <= NF; i++) a[$i] = a[$i] FS $1 }' input.csv`. by setting up the delimiter and parsing in loop., but not getting any. I am not sure on where to insert print here.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/476222/13792

Comment: what happens when you process abc twice ? Only first time counts or you should have multiple abc lines in the output file ?

Comment: no i want unique values only.. so only once i want an entry

Comment: Add your code to your question to avoid getting more downvotes. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this code does :

```
awk -F\| '{ for(i=2; i <= NF; i++) a[$i] = a[$i] FS $1 }' input.csv
```

-F sets the delimiter to |, awk process line by line your file, creates a map named 'a', reads from column 2 until the end and fill the map using the current cell processed as key and the current cell + file separator + value in the first column as value.

When awk ends processing the first line, 'a' is :

```
a['abc'] = 'abc|1234'
a['cde'] = 'cde|1234'
a['fgh'] = 'fgh|1234'
```

This script does not print anything.

What you want is something like this :

```
awk -F'|' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if(seen[$i] != 1){print $i, strftime(); seen[$i]=1}}}' OFS='|' input.csv
```

-F sets the input delimiter to |, OFS does the same for the output delimiter.
For each value from the column 2 to the end of the line, we check if it has already been seen before. If not, we print the value and the time of process. Then we register the value in a map so we can avoid to process it again.

Output :

```
abc|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
cde|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
fgh|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
ijk|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
lmn|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
klm|Thu Oct 18 10:40:13 CEST 2018
```

You can change the format of sysdate. See documentation of gawk strftime [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Comment: Thank u so much.... instead of timestamp.. how ll i replace with just date?

Comment: @Vandhana I gave you the documentation of strftime. Just use strftime with the format you want, like strftime("%Y%m%d")